# How to parse URL with multiple values into multiple int

Tags: c#, query-string

I have a query string that I need to split into 2 separate int and I'm having a hard time getting it to work and a hard time understanding other examples. Basically I want to split the date part of a url for example - www.website.com?2019&9. Here is what I have been trying to get to work. I know there is definitely a more elegant way to do this but I'm new to using query strings.

```
        string QueryString = Request.QueryString.ToString();
        int [] QueryInt = new int[2];
        int k = 0;
        string[] QuerySplit = QueryString.Split('&');
        foreach (var item in QuerySplit)
        {
            int.TryParse(QueryString, out QueryInt[k]);
            k++;
        }
```

Comment: Your URL looks weird. It should be `...?param1=value1&param2=value2`. And do you know which parameters you're looking for? You should just be able to do `string value = Request.QueryString["parameterName"];` Check out [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.querystring?view=netframework-4.8) for more information and examples.

Comment: I do know which ones I need. I appreciate the advice I didn't know they should look like that. i will check the documentation.

Comment: No problem. If you want a list of numbers, you might consider something like `...?values=2019,9,1,2,3` or some other delimiter that isn't a special query string character. Then you could do `List<int> values = Request.QueryString["values"].Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `Request.QueryString["Param"];` as suggested by itsme86. This isn't the prettiest solution and I'm sure there is a better one but it works and thats the most important thing.

Parameters in URL should look like

> `exampleurl.com/?year=2019&month=9`.

```
    string monthQuery = Request.QueryString["month"];
    int monthVal = 0;
    int.TryParse(monthQuery, out monthVal);
    string yearQuery = Request.QueryString["year"];
    int yearVal = 0;
    int.TryParse(yearQuery, out yearVal);
```